# Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (1,)

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I am trying to use Dense function from keras to train neural network. However, I keep getting this error message

> Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (1,)

my input is 1 dimensional (for example [1,2,3,4]). is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The [Dense function](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/)

*output = activation(dot(input, kernel) + bias)*

requires both input and kernel, so its parameter must have at least 2nd rank (have 2 dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

That is easy just use input_shape=(1,)

For example this is a simple for a classification problem with only 1 input dimension.

```
X = np.random.randn(1000,) #create some dummy data
y = np.random.randint(0,3,(1000,)) #create some dummy data
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit your model
model.fit(X,y, epochs=100)
```